# Problems using netbeans 7.01 with CMake 2.8.6

Tags: netbeans, cmake

so once again, I'm having a little problem I can't figure out myself. Meaning, I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is, I just can't fix it.

I'm developing in C++ using Netbeans 7.01 with CMake 2.8.6. However, when I'm trying to build a project, I get the following error from CMake:

> CMake Error: The path to the source directory:
>
> H:/Projects/Netbeans/CppApplication_1/CONF=Release
>
> contains unsupported character '='.
>
> Please use a different source directory name.

Please note, that "CONF=Release" isn't a folder. It seems to be a configuration flag set by Netbeans, as it changes when I'm trying a debug build. So, my guess here is, that theres a space missing, or something similar. Unfortunately, I can't figure out where to change that. There are no options in any related Netbeans window, I can't find anything related in the configuration files for netbeans itself or the project either.

Did anyone here have experienced the same problem and found a solution to it? I would be very glad to hear it. If there's any information missing, let me know, I will add them as fast as possible.

Edit:
Just noticed there is already version 7.1 of netbeans, nice to know. However, even with this version, the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the command you ran to allow for the error to be identified. However, it looks like you missed the "source-path" parameter.

The cmake command ends with the path to source and should be something like:

```
cmake -D CONF=Release <path to source>
```